# Consuming RestApi with Requests gives SSL module is not available error

Tags: python, visual-studio, rest, python-requests

I am trying to consume a `RestAPI` that I have already tested in `C#` but now I want to rewrite the Client in `Python` for learing effects. I am coding in `Visual Studio` under `Windows`.

What I did yet is:

```
import requests

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

def getToken(self):
    endpoint = "https://test.com/web/service/auth/token"
    headers = {
        "username" : self.username,
        "password" : self.password,
        "environment" : "env_me",
        "grant_type" : "password",
        "Content_Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    r = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers)
    return print(r.json())


myObj = myClass("UN","PS")
token = myObj.getToken()
print(token)
```

Running this code gives me the error:

```
SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'test.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /web/service/auth/token (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Since I could find any help for this I was trying to `Import ssl` but this gives me the error: The specific module could not be found. `from ssl import ...` gives me a whole bunch of stuff to choose but I do not know what to choose since I am new to Python. Could anyone help me get rid of the error?

Comment: Are you using anaconda by any chance? The anconda seems to ship with its own ssl libraries.

Comment: Yes, I am using anaconade. Can you tell me how to import these?

Comment: try to install certifi -- "pip install certifi" or "conda install -c auto certifi"

Comment: I have installed certifi and added it without error to the project "Import certifi" but still get the SSLError

Comment: see this discussion. https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/python-feedstock/issues/13. The solution might involve a downgrade.